# How to add the Ws2_32.lib file in meson?

Tags: meson-build

I'm using the meson build system. How can I link the winsock file in my `meson.build`? I tried using `dependency('Ws2_32')` but that just returns an error that it could not find the library. I'm using meson+C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the path to your lib file, you can create the dependency like this :

```
my_inc = include_directories(...)
my_lib = static_library(...)
my_dep = declare_dependency(link_with : my_lib, include_directories : my_inc)
```

[link to the meson documentation](https://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html#declaring-your-own)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [find_library() method](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#compiler-object):

```
compiler = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
dep = compiler.find_library('ws2_32', required: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `compiler.find_library()`. The documentation says:

> By default the library is searched for in the system library directory
> (e.g. /usr/lib).

You can determine the value of you system library directory (`libdir`) by typing `meson configure` while in your build directory.
Apparently, [`libdir` is always relative to `prefix`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#get_option):

> Note that the value returned for built-in options that end in dir such
> as [..] libdir is always a path relative to (and inside) the
> prefix.